# Multiple View creation via 1 script/file

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create multiple views (90+, and this number can change) in SQL Server.
Each CREATE is successfully executing, but real problem comes when I put them together to execute.
ex.:

```
create view v1 as select * from t1 where c1=cond1;
create view v2 as select * from t2 where c2=cond2 and c3=cond3;
create view v3 as select * from t3 where c3 between value1 and value2;
 create view v4 as select * from t4 where c4=cond4 and cond5;
```

I tried using go after each create command, tried defining blocks for each create(begin...end), still the same error :Msg 104309, Level 16, State 1, Line 84...There are no batches in the input script.

Please help how to resolve this error. Cheers, BauV

Comment: Executing via which tool? Both SSMS and `sqlcmd` support `GO`. Also, internal SQL Server errors have numbers under 50000, so your error comes from some other software.

Comment: `CREATE VIEW` must be the only statement in the batch, so you *need* batch separators, if the application supports it. If not, you'll need to execute each one separately.

Comment: I am executing this on Synapse using SSMS.